# YARN: get containers by applicationId

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I'd like to list the nodes on which the containers are running for a particular MR job.
I only have the `application_id`.
Is it possible to do it with *Hadoop REST API* and/or through *command line*?

Answer (score 10):

This can be done using the `yarn` command.

1. Run `yarn applicationattempt -list <Application Id>` to get an app attempt id
2. Run `yarn container -list <Application Attempt Id>` to get the container ids
3. Run `yarn container -status <Container Id>` to get the host for any particular container.

If you want this in a bash script or want to get every host for an application with a large number of containers you will probably want to parse out the attempt/container id and host, but this is at least a start.

Answer (score 0):

You can find them using Resource manager UI. Find your application by ID among the existing applications and click on the link with ID you have. You will see your application stats. Fint the tracking URL and click on the link 'History'. There you'll be able to find the tasks in your map operation and recude optration. You can open each task and see the information, to which node it was assigned for, nubmer of attempts, logs for each task and attempts and lots of other usefull information.

For getting the information about the container status from command line you can use [yarn container -status](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YarnCommands.html#container) command from bash

Comment: Thanks. I know how to find it on the UI, that's why I explicitly mentioned the other ways I'm looking for

Comment: @Bruckwald if you want to use command line, then probably you should use 'yarn' command, 'yarn container -status' command in your particular case to get what you want